# Data usage calculation in Android NetworkStats class

Tags: android, networking, android-api-levels

I saw Android has `NetworkStats.Bucket` class from which we can query the network data usage of an app. `getRxBytes()` and `getRxPackets()` return the number of bytes and packets received.

I'm curious is there any delay when updating the data usage?

Besides, I'm curious is there any relation between `getRxBytes()` and `getRxPackets()`? Does the number of bytes received include the header of packets(Ethernet, IP, TCP/UDP) or it only include the data attached with each packet?

Does anyone has any idea?